# Pattern Printing in C for printing numbers in vertical pattern

Tags: c, design-patterns, pattern-matching

I wrote a function to print the below pattern.
**For example**, if the n value is **4** the pattern is

```
1
2 7
3 6 8
4 5 9 10
```

Or if the value of n is **5**, then the pattern is

```
1
2 9
3 8 10
4 7 11 14
5 6 12 13 15
```

My function gives me the first two block but not the next block. I'm stuck here for long time!

My function is

```
int printPattern(int n) {
    int row, column, fwdCtr = 1, evenCtr = 0, ctr = n;
    for(row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
        fwdCtr = row;
        for(column = 1; column <= row; column++) {
            if(column % 2 != 0) {
                printf("%d ", fwdCtr++);
            } else {
                evenCtr = fwdCtr + ctr;
                printf("%d ", evenCtr);
                ctr = ctr - 2;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }     
}
```

What I get is

```
1
2 7
3 6 4
4 5 5 4
```

Please give suggestions of changes!

Comment: I'd prepare the values in a 2d array and then print the lower  left triangle of the array. Maybe there is a more clever way.

Comment: So the issue is that the 3rd and 4th cols aren't working.  But they're doing exactly what you tell them to.  `printf("%d ", fwdCtr++);` is executed on every odd column, and results in printing the column and then incrementing it.  Also, `evenCtr = fwdCtr + ctr;` is executed every even row, with `ctr` being decremented twice and `fwdCtr` being incremented once between executions (resulting in a net decrement of 1).  This is exactly what you notice.  If it's not what you want, then this is probably the time to rewrite your code as to let it be legible enough to not cause you confusion.

Comment: I would suggest building a model first (possibly utilizing a 2D array as suggested above), and then printing the contents of that model afterwards.  Working without a model and attempting to print the values purely based on the input is causing you confusion.

Comment: Can you please help me with the code? I even tried the 2D structure but failed getting a result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=i; ++j)
        {
            // Calculate the numbers used so far by previous columns
            int x = 0;
            for(int v=0; v<j;++v)
            {
                x = x + (n-v);  
            }

            if ((j % 2) == 0)
            {
                // even columns
                printf("%d ", x+i-j+1);
            }
            else
            {
                // odd columns
                printf("%d ", x+n-i);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    f(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 
2 9 
3 8 10 
4 7 11 14 
5 6 12 13 15
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: It is helpful but I would say if possible add some explanation (maybe one line).

Answer (score 1):

The easy thing to do is just print the right number based on the row and column and the value of `n`, like this

```
int main(void)
{
    int n = 20;
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= row; col++)
           printf("%3d ", 1 + col*n - (col-1)*col/2 + (col%2 ? n-1-row : row-col));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one line I see... the only thing is for higher values it might overflow. Isn't it?

Comment: Hm ye..but that's also a case...just saying.